# brightness issue when mouse over the link in windows settings

Tags: windows, windows-10, asus-laptop, brightness, mouse-cursor

i've just bought a new asus laptop ux330ua with preinstalled windows 10 pro on it.

Issue: when i mouse over the link in windows settings(for example) the screen becomes darker little bit then when i move my mouse out it back to initial brightness state.

This issue occurs sometimes in browsers but i cant reproduce it, because it happens not for all links on the page.
Sometimes brightness is changing during scrolling on the page and when i select deselect text in browser(just found out this issue)

On the screenshots below you can see two steps for reproducing this issue: i open settings then mouse over the link and then brightness has been changed then mouse out and brightness went back to initial state.

[image: darker]

[image: initial]

Comment: are we talking complete screen changes or just the links?

Comment: screen changes. And the main problem i dont know how to google this, is it somehow related to resolution in windows(qhd 3200x1800) or  is it the issue of windows 10 or asus issue. :(

Comment: It's a very weird specific issue that I have never heard of before. Does video driver have an update?? I would start there.

Comment: yes, it is up to date. Interesting thing that http://i.imgur.com/kJ6evU1.png here it changes brightness a bit only on 'change plan settings' links, when i mouse over on other links it looks fine.